# How to setup multipath

Tags: hard-drive, multipath

I am trying to use multipath for the first time. And even that I have read the documentation both here at Ubuntu and on Redhat, I'm not coming closer to a solution.

I have 4 disks

- /dev/sdb
- /dev/sdc
- /dev/sdd
- /dev/sde

What I'm trying to setup is this

```
mpatha    
    /dev/sdb
    /dev/sdc

mpathb
    /dev/sdb
    /dev/sdc
```

But for now I get this

```
sdb  259:0        0  1.1T  0 disk
ââmpatha 253:1    0  1.1T  0 mpath
sdc  259:1        0  1.1T  0 disk
ââmpathb 253:2    0  1.1T  0 mpath
sdd  259:2        0  1.1T  0 disk
ââmpathd 253:3    0  1.1T  0 mpath
sde  259:3        0  1.1T  0 disk
```

My config looks like this:

```
defaults {
    user_friendly_names     yes
    find_multipaths         no
    max_fds                 32
    uid_attribute           ID_WWN
    path_checker            directio
}

blacklist_exceptions {
  property "(ID_WWN|SCSI_IDENT_.*|ID_SERIAL|DEVTYPE)"
  devnode "sd*"
```

But how to specify which drives goes to which MultiPath groups?

Comment: Are those really 4 disks or rather 2 disks connected over 2 paths? You cannot group different disks with multipath, only disks that have more than one path/connection.

Comment: Hi Thomas, yes this is two disk over 2 paths. How can it see it is the samme disk but over different paths?

Comment: To check the device, look at the serial numbers or WWNs of the disks with `lsscsi -w`. For the multipath configuration, start with a simple default configuration which you can find at */usr/share/doc/device-mapper-multipath/multipath.conf* and set your own blacklist, which excludes all `sd*` devices. Then build up your rules on a running configuration.

Comment: Thanks Thomas The clue was that disk should have the same WWN and the way I had setup the 2. path gave another WWN so when this was fixed it worked. Thanks to point that out.